# Can a chopper lift off with only 1 jerry can of fuel?

Tags: dayz-2012

I found a Mi-17 on the North West Airfield (without fuel). I filled it with one jerry can of fuel and tried to lift off. The rotors were turning, but I couldn't lift off.

(When I went out to get more fuel I died so I wasn't able to test it).

Was it just buggy, or do I need more fuel to lift off with a chopper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mi-17 is capable of flying as long it has fuel, even with just a bit of fuel. But the Mi-17 don't work only with fuel.

If didn't work, may have been for several reasons, such as:

- Engine or main rotary parts needed repairs
- Lack of knowledge of how to pilot Mi-17

  - Arrows to move
  - Q - Up
  - Z - Down
  - X - Turn Left
  - C - Turn Right
- Bug

Comment: Everything was green and I flew with a littlebird before.

Comment: Then it only can be some bug, what was the version of the server?

Comment: my client version was the ARMA2_OA_Build_104648 beta Patch
The server 1.6.2

Comment: That is your ARMA OA client version, i'm asking the dayz server version where you were playing

Comment: The server was a 1.62 server